# How to install Truffle

Tags: macos, truffle, cryptocurrency

I was stuck when I install truffle to my Mac PC.
I tried to install it with `npm install -g truffle` and it worked after I made a folder for global install.
However, when I try to run Truffle

```
truffle init
```

it returns `-bash: truffle: command not found`
I also reinstall it and run it again but nothing was changed.
[image]

How can I deal with this issue ?
It would be really appreciated if you explained in detail.

Comment: I see some suggestion in https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/919
May be helpfull to you

Answer (score 2):

I think on windows you are suppose to use truffle.cmd instead of truffle.

So try,

```
truffle.cmd init
```

Keeping in mind that truffle init is depreciated so you should try using

```
truffle.cmd unbox metacoin
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can reinstall it by this commands 

     npm uninstall -g truffle
```

Install it by

```
     npm install -f truffle
```

Thanks